# tensorflow v2.0.0-alpha0 Build error "swif" on windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, build, windows-10

I am trying to build tensorflow v2.0.0-alpha0 on windows 10. I am following [this guide](https://medium.com/@amsokol.com/update-2-how-to-build-and-install-tensorflow-gpu-cpu-for-windows-from-source-code-using-bazel-61c26553f7e8) and i followed every step. I am using this command for build:

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Which gives me this error:

```
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'swift/repositories.bzl': no such package '@build_bazel_rules_swift//swift': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 164
                _clone_or_update(ctx)
        File "C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 74, in _clone_or_update
                fail(("error cloning %s:\n%s" % (ctx....)))
error cloning build_bazel_rules_swift:
+ cd C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external
+ rm -rf C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external/build_bazel_rules_swift C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external/build_bazel_rules_swift
/usr/bin/rm: missing operand
Try '/usr/bin/rm --help' for more information.
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'swift/repositories.bzl': no such package '@build_bazel_rules_swift//swift': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 164
                _clone_or_update(ctx)
        File "C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 74, in _clone_or_update
                fail(("error cloning %s:\n%s" % (ctx....)))
error cloning build_bazel_rules_swift:
+ cd C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external
+ rm -rf C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external/build_bazel_rules_swift C:/users/tensoruser/_bazel_tensoruser/37wcdhpe/external/build_bazel_rules_swift
/usr/bin/rm: missing operand
Try '/usr/bin/rm --help' for more information.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.680s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
    Fetching @build_bazel_rules_swift; Cloning tags/0.6.0 of https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_swift.git
```

The Environment is:

- Windows 10 x64
- Python 3.6.6 x64
- bazel v0.23.0
- CUDA v10.1 x64
- cuDNN v10.1 x64

I have tried the solutions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25747), and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/26079), but no joy.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following line in the WORKSPACE file in the root directory of tensorflow:

```
# Apple and Swift rules.
http_archive(
    name = "build_bazel_rules_apple",
    sha256 = "73b4980a318d203d3307f850e27e66ec5cc8d223147a3475a6f11597eb6438a5",
    strip_prefix = "rules_apple-0.13.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_apple/archive/0.13.0.tar.gz"],
)
http_file(
    name = "xctestrunner",
    executable = 1,
    urls = ["https://github.com/google/xctestrunner/releases/download/0.2.6/ios_test_runner.par"],
)
load("@build_bazel_rules_apple//apple:repositories.bzl", "apple_rules_dependencies")
apple_rules_dependencies()
load("@build_bazel_rules_swift//swift:repositories.bzl", "swift_rules_dependencies")
swift_rules_dependencies()
```

It seemed that these lines would build Apple MacOS version which not needed by other platform.